# rails 3.1 deployment on heroku .css isn't precompiled error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**Update**

I got this error because I had a public.css and public.js file that was not compiled with the rest of the .css and .js files. The solution was to add this line to the production.rb file

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js public.css  )
```

As you see from the comment all files names application are already added. So, I just had to add the ones that was not called application.

Hope it helps someone!

**Original question**

I have this gem file

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem "heroku"
gem 'thin'
gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
gem 'tabulous'
gem 'json'
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem "devise"
gem "redcarpet"

group :assets do

  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
end
```

when I deploy with "git push heroku master" I see this

```
Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       mkdir -p /tmp/build_2m34y4hj01m4o/public/assets
       mkdir -p /tmp/build_2m34y4hj01m4o/public/assets
       mkdir -p /tmp/build_2m34y4hj01m4o/public/assets
       mkdir -p /tmp/build_2m34y4hj01m4o/public/assets/admin
       mkdir -p /tmp/build_2m34y4hj01m4o/public/assets/admin
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
-----> Compiled slug size is 31.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://maktaba.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku
```

but in the heroku logs I get this ActionView::Template::Error. css isn't precompiled
Strange.. I thougt it was looking at the deployment feedback

```
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered public/index.html.erb within layouts/first (0.7ms)
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (public/public.css isn't precompiled):
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     2: <html>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     3: <head>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:   <title>Maktaba</title>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "public/public" %>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "public/public" %>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/public/index.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_public_index_html_erb___1726244208117637261_45234420'
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/public_controller.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in index'
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:
2011-11-23T22:59:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/public_controller.rb:12:in `index'
```

Can any of you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: adding the line `config.assets.precompile += %w( public.js public.css  )` to production.rb then running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` followed by a push and heroku restart did the trick for me. thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on your local code
- Commit the changes and deploy to heroku

If this is your first time deploying your app to heroku, you may experience more errors after this is resolved. Let me know what happens.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you need to run precompilation for your **production** environment:

- Run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on local
- Commit and deploy to Heroku

More broadly, the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar) describe three options for asset compilation for Rails 3.1+ on Cedar:

1. Compile locally (covered in this answer)
2. Compile during slug compilation
3. Compile during runtime