# CSS not recognized on Heroku deploy of rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I know this question has been asked [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719541/css-loading-locally-but-not-in-heroku-for-a-rails-app), and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902005/cant-load-custom-css-on-heroku?rq=1), and [even here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250344/rails-3-1-deployment-on-heroku-css-isnt-precompiled-error)... I have tried all of these changes, yet am still having no such luck. My heroku app lives at http://calm-mountain-2401.herokuapp.com/, and I am extremely frustrated by this. My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:      https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


gem 'jquery-turbolinks'


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

I have been able to successfully deploy, however the code is very obviously not CSS-ified. Any help would be much appreciated!

Alex

EDIT: here is the output of git push heroku master

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 496 bytes, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --  binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.5)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.8.0)
       Using atomic (1.1.14)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0)
       Using mime-types (1.25)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.15)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (2.0.1)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jbuilder (1.5.1)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
       Using jquery-turbolinks (2.0.1)
       Using json (1.8.0)
       Using pg (0.16.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Using rails (4.0.0)
       Using rdoc (3.12.2)
       Using sass (3.2.10)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Using sdoc (0.3.20)
       Using uglifier (2.2.1)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> WARNINGS:
       Include 'rails_12factor' gem to enable all platform features
       See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems for more information.

       You have not declared a Ruby version in your Gemfile.
       To set your Ruby version add this line to your Gemfile:
       ruby '2.0.0'
       # See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions for more information."
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 38.5MB
-----> Launching... done, v8
       http://calm-mountain-2401.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:calm-mountain-2401.git
   6e49406..83bf74d  master -> master`
```

Comment: Can you add the output you see when you `git push heroku master`?

Comment: Have you tried pre-compiling your assets? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: yes, and then i committed them to git and tried to redeploy my app to the same result

Comment: Try adding the rails_12factor and rails3_serve_static_assets (I'm aware you aren't using Rails 3) gems.

Comment: Try `rake assets:clean` to remove old assets or `rake assets:clobber` to remove all precompile assets.  Commit this and then push it and let Heroku precompile your assets.  This may solve the problem.  Having visited your site, the application.css file is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted precompiling your assets explicitly?

```
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked the solution of pdoherty926.

Try adding the rails_12factor and rails3_serve_static_assets (I'm aware you aren't using Rails 3) gems.